# NGINX 405 Not Allowed when uploading file

Tags: curl, nginx

I need to redirect all file upload request https://example.com/year2017/monthsept/upload/ to go to https://example.com/upload/

In nginx config I have the following location/rewrite rule within the server block. However, I receive 405 error.

```
location ~ ^/year2017/monthsept/upload/(.*) {
rewrite ^year2017/monthsept/upload/$1 /upload/$1 permanent;
}

$ curl --verbose --upload-file test.txt https://example.com/year2017/monthsept/upload/
```

> PUT /year2017/monthsept/upload/test.txt HTTP/1.1
>   < HTTP/1.1 405 Not Allowed
>   * HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
>   * Closing connection 0

I have updated the rewrite rule so often but no joy.

What would the correct nginx rule for this be?

Answer (score 0):

You never rewrite a POST or a PUT request. Because that will change the request to a GET request. A POST/PUT request should always be processed as it. So you just proxy it back to nginx with the correct path

```
location ~ ^/year2017/monthsept/upload/(.*) {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/upload/$1;
}
```

Comment: Hi Tarun, 
At this point, I should add the the nginx is a load balancer with 2 upstream servers. How would the additional proxy_pass work with load balancing?  Remove the IP address like this?

location ~ ^/year2017/monthsept/upload/(.*) {
    proxy_pass /upload/$1;
}

Comment: This helped and I now have it working as expected using 

    `location ~ ^/year2017/monthsept/upload/(.*) { 
        proxy_pass example.com/upload/$1; 
    }`

Comment: Try the approach i mentioned and add `proxy_set_header Host $host`. Because using `example.com` means routing to the external IP and using localhost/127.0.0.1 will be better thing to do